# How to write calculate columns in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

This is a sample of my database:
[image]

I'm trying to write a query that returns the following:

```
worker_id,
avg salary for 2020 (basic_salary+bonus),
basic_salary for 2021,
ever been in level C (yes/no),
average basic_salary \>6000 (yes/no),
how many salaries the employee had until today.
```

here's a query i wrote:

```
// select worker_id, AVG(CASE WHEN year(month)=2020
                THEN BASIC_SALARY+bonus
                ELSE NULL END) AS avg_2020,
avg(case when year(month)=2021 
then BASIC_SALARY
else null end) as avg_2021,
case when t1.level='C' then 'YES' 
else 'NO'
end as 'Level C',
CASE WHEN AVG(BASIC_SALARY) >6000 
            THEN 'yes'
            ELSE 'no' 
       END AS 'above_6000',
count(BASIC_SALARY) 'HowManySalaries'
from [workers_table] t1
join data t2
on t1.level=t2.level
group by worker_id,t1.level
order by WORKER_ID
//
```

and the results:

```
worker_id   avg_2020    avg_2021    Level C above_6000  HowManySalaries
2011-11-11  NULL    3500    NO  no  4
2011-11-11  NULL    5000    NO  no  2
2011-11-11  NULL    4000    YES yes 3
2011-11-12  8666    4500    NO  yes 4
2011-11-12  9666    NULL    NO  yes 3
2011-11-12  7000    6000    YES no  2
2011-11-12  9000    NULL    NO  no  1
2011-11-13  NULL    10000   NO  yes 3
2011-11-13  9000    4500    NO  no  3
2011-11-13  10000   18000   YES yes 5
2011-11-13  12500   6750    NO  yes 5
2011-11-14  NULL    3600    NO  no  1
2011-11-14  NULL    7200    NO  yes 2
2011-11-14  NULL    4800    YES no  1
```

maybe there is a better way to write the query? i need to get 1 line for each worker_id.

Comment: (Somewhat unrelated) The correct term to use is _query_, not script.

Comment: Hy, please [don't upload table as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options.

Comment: You do need to remove `level` from the grouping to get a single aggregate per worker. It appears that you can skip levels though (refer to 01/10/2021). What happens if you jump straight to D? Should that count toward your C total? Also since the salary within a single month can be split, your averages will be weighted incorrectly I have to imagine.

Comment: `case when min(case when level = 'C' then 'Yes' else null end) = 'Yes' then 'Yes' else 'No' end` or `max(case when level = 'C' then 'Yes' else 'No' end)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. I just briefly checked through the result/values, so it may not be 100% correct, but seems correct. Double check for correctness before using this. :)

```sql
select 
    worker_id,
    AVG(CASE WHEN year(w.month)=2020 THEN w.BASIC_SALARY+b.bonus ELSE NULL END) AS avg_2020,
    AVG(CASE WHEN year(w.month)=2021 THEN w.BASIC_SALARY ELSE NULL END) AS avg_2021,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN w.level='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS 'Level C',
    CASE WHEN AVG(w.BASIC_SALARY) > 6000 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS 'above_6000',
    COUNT(w.BASIC_SALARY) 'HowManySalaries'
FROM workers_table w
JOIN data b on b.level=w.level
GROUP BY w.worker_id
```

---

In your query you're grouping by both worker id and the bonus level. So your rows end up with all possible combinations between those two values. Limiting it to just the worker_id results in one row per worker.
Though this will cause your "in level C" column to not work properly since a basic `CASE WHEN` isn't paying attention to all rows given for a specific worker_id. Expanding the `CASE WHEN` with a `MAX`-aggregation will fix this though.